# How to initialize typeorm entity by considering its nullable columns

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I would like to set value to typeorm entity and insert them to DB.

```
import { PricingPatternElement } from file

               const Element:PricingPatternElement = {
                  displayOrder : 10,
                  elementName : "test",
                  createdAt  : getCurrentDate(),
                  createdBy :  "test"
                }
```

When I set above value to `PricingPatternElement` it returned following error.

```
Type '{ displayOrder: number; elementName: string; createdAt: Date; createdBy: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'PricingPatternElement': pricingPatternElementId, minPrice, maxPrice, priceInterval, and 15 more.
```

it shows 15 members are not set . but actually, I set `nullable` as follows
so that I need not set nullable values.

my desired goal is to set value avoiding to set `nullable` columns.

I must set only `5 columns`according to its entity definitions.

```
import {
  BaseEntity,
  Column,
  Entity,
  Index,
  JoinColumn,
  ManyToOne,
  OneToMany,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from "typeorm";
import { PricingPattern } from "./pricingPattern";
import { InputPricingElement } from "./inputPricingElement";
@Index("pricing_pattern_element_pkc", ["pricingPatternElementId"], {
  unique: true,
})
@Entity("pricing_pattern_element", { schema: "atai" })
export class PricingPatternElement extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
    type: "bigint",
    name: "pricing_pattern_element_id",
  })
  pricingPatternElementId: string;

  @Column("integer", { name: "display_order" })
  displayOrder: number;

  @Column("text", { name: "element_name" })
  elementName: string;

  @Column("integer", { name: "min_price", nullable: true })
  minPrice: number | null;

  @Column("integer", { name: "max_price", nullable: true })
  maxPrice: number | null;

  @Column("integer", { name: "price_interval", nullable: true })
  priceInterval: number | null;

  @Column("character varying", {
    name: "icon_image",
    nullable: true,
    length: 256,
  })
  iconImage: string | null;

  @Column("text", { name: "additional_explanation", nullable: true })
  additionalExplanation: string | null;

  @Column("integer", { name: "default_element_price", nullable: true })
  defaultElementPrice: number | null;

  @Column("timestamp without time zone", { name: "created_at" })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column("character varying", { name: "created_by", length: 256 })
  createdBy: string;

  @Column("timestamp without time zone", { name: "updated_at", nullable: true })
  updatedAt: Date | null;

  @Column("character varying", {
    name: "updated_by",
    nullable: true,
    length: 256,
  })
  updatedBy: string | null;

  @Column("timestamp without time zone", { name: "revoked_at", nullable: true })
  revokedAt: Date | null;

  @Column("character varying", {
    name: "revoked_by",
    nullable: true,
    length: 256,
  })
  revokedBy: string | null;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => PricingPattern,
    (pricingPattern) => pricingPattern.pricingPatternElements
  )
  @JoinColumn([
    { name: "pricing_pattern_id", referencedColumnName: "pricingPatternId" },
  ])
  pricingPattern: PricingPattern;

  @OneToMany(
    () => InputPricingElement,
    (inputPricingElement) => inputPricingElement.pricingPatternElement
  )
  inputPricingElements: InputPricingElement[];
}
```

How can I set value avoiding to set nullable columns ?
Thanks

Comment: There is a fine line between null and undefined. Did you try makin your properties optional?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the way is to use "as":

```
   const Element = {
                  displayOrder : 10,
                  elementName : "test",
                  createdAt  : getCurrentDate(),
                  createdBy :  "test"
                } as PricingPatternElement;
```

But you should understand that if there will be default params it will not exists in this object (but it could be used in tests, for example)

Probably you trying to find https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/repository-api:

```
const user = repository.create({
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Timber",
    lastName: "Saw",
});
```

This will create an entity without inserting it into db